# Capitalize first lower-case letter in specific location

Tags: awk, sed

I have a lot of .htm files. Title tag has something similar
19.10.2014 - pila and it's always different text.
How it is possible to make pila to Pila.
What i need is a onliner which finds all .htm files in a folder and changes title sections first letter to uppercase?
So far i have:

```
awk -i inplace '{a=FILENAME;sub(/\.htm$/,"",a);gsub(/<title>[^<]*<\/title>/,"<title>"a"</title>")}1' *.htm
```

That onliner replaces title tag original text with actual file name.
So basically i need a sub for awk (i think).
Is it possible to do and how?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (using GNU awk for 3rd arg to match()):

```
gawk '
match($0,/(.*<title>.*-\s+)(.)([^<]*<\/title>.*)/,a) {
    $0 = a[1] toupper(a[2]) a[3]
}1' *.htm
```